# Compile method of Expression<TDelegate> makes a fatal error on Android

Tags: c#, compilation, lambda, unity-game-engine, expression

Can a Compile() method make a fatal error enough to turn off the application on android platform?

When I call that method below about 50~100 times on android platform, my application gets 
turned off. but on UnityEditor it works well.
There's no null value or invalid param or any expression. And the lambda.ToString() log on android 
is exactly the same as the thing on Unity Editor.
I have no idea why that method with such a simple expression makes the application turned 
off. It's getting me crazy.

```
protected virtual object VisitMemberAccess(MemberExpression m)
{
    var member = Expression.Convert(m, typeof(object));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(member);
    var getter = lambda.Compile(); //<===== this is the one who gets me crazy.
    return getter();
}
```

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. so do not misuse it.

Comment: I got it. thanks for yor advice.